# how to Define a struct type to represent the combination of a name and a zip code in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am a C++ newbie. I am more familiar with Java programming using Eclipse software.

I was asked to do the following:

> Create an array of 20 structs.
>
> Read names and zip codes from an input file and assign them to the array of structs.
>
> Print the array values in their original input order.
>
> Sort the array of structs into alphabetical order by name.
>
> Print the sorted array values. For each of the different zip codes represented, print a list of all names with that zip code (there will be no more than 4 different zip codes).

Where and how do I go about this?

Comment: You may want to read into structures(http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask people to write code for you.  Please put in the effort to research the issue and attempt to write the code yourself first. Talk to your teacher. Read your learning material. Write some code and try to compile it. Then ask questions here about any specific issues you run into.

Comment: ok thanks. let me review that link.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to represent the zipcode.
I recommend using a string.

Here's the struct:

```
struct Name_Zipcode
{
  std::string name;
  std::string zipcode;
};
```

Some useful methods to add:

- Constructors (default and copy)
- Assignment
- Destructors
- Formatted input, from `std::istream`
- Formatted output, to `std::ostream`
- Default ordering, i.e. overload `operator <`
- And equality operator.

You can search StackOverflow for "c++ read file struct" for examples on how to read data from a text file into an instance.